# QGIS create atlas Overviewmap with a bufferzone for surrounding points around the atlasobject

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

My goal is to create a zone of visibilty around an atlasobject to show surrounding points and display them in a different style as they aren't the main focus just a little extra.
the bufferzone should be around 50 meters in diameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own Question now as i thought i don't really want anybody to search long for the solution like i did ;)

First of all i created a copy of the original vectordata (this will be the data that gets buffered).

After that i made the main data the atlascoverage layer as usual and set a field to display the current object.
Then I switched to rulebased styling and entered the following Rule

*"Fieldname" = attribute(@atlas_feature,'Fieldname')*

after that i went to my buffer layer switched to rule based styling too and entered the following rule

*CASE WHEN $id is@altlas_featureid THEN NULL WHEN $id is not @atlas_featureid THEN within($geometry,buffer(@atlas_geometry,distance)) END*

a distance of 0.0005 resultet in a buffer about 50m in diameter which is what i wanted

The result off all this i now have my main layer which is controlled by the atlas and my buffer Layer which is indirectly controlled by the atlas and only displays the surrounding objects and not the main object aswell.